# Rails Active Record - Get ids array from relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking for an easy/fast way of getting an array of ids from a Active Record relation.

Currently i have:

```
product_ids = Product.select(:id).where(:colour => 'blue').all.map{|p|p.id}
```

But that's messy and requires a map..

Something like this would be cooler:

```
product_ids = Product.where(:colour => 'blue').ids
```

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Pluck is the best solution here but just as a btw: instead of `map{|p| p.id}` can you write `map(&:id)`. This is true for all enumerators (`each`, `any?`, `select`, `reject` etc.), and will call the symbol on each object it loops through.

Comment: oh yeah, i knew about `map(&:id)`  just had a mental blank when writing this up :P

Answer (score 80, accepted):

A little bit more neat solution:

```
Product.where(:colour => 'blue').pluck(:id)
```

In recent versions of Rails the `ids` method can be used.

```
Product.where(color: 'blue').ids
```

Answer (score 15):

Have been reading through the rails 4 docs and it looks like they support the `ids` method that I said would be cool in the question now.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-ids

Nice to know the team are reading my mind :)

Answer (score 14):

To build on the previous answers, if you are working through an association, you can just append `_ids` to the query.

So in your example, if a `Supplier` `has_many` `Products`, then:

```
supplier.product_ids
```

would return your array of product ids that belongs to the supplier.